# Regex for password - Not maximum 4 repeating characters

Tags: regex, passwords

I need password field validation that should block if more than 4 repeating characters.

> Expected Result: Eg: abcde@123 - true aaaacad@123 - false (5 "a"
>   present)

```
^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!_%*#?&.])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*#_?&.]{8,}$
```

I tried those solutions but its checking continuous repeating characters

Comment: I tried those solutions but its checking continuous repeating characters. But i need to find contains more than 4 repeating characters.

Comment: You might find [Reference - Password Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48345922/3600709) useful.